# How can I make a tooltip link to another page?

Tags: yii, tooltip

In the data gridview, I am able to put tooltip (http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/javascript.html#tooltips) by using headerHtmlOptions and get the data from the database.

My problem is that I can't find a way to put a link in the tooltip. For example, "This is tooltip. See more.." If 'See more..' is clicked it should go to another page. Thanks.

Comment: Your tooltip have some div. Bind click function to it with jquery and change location on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this extension (http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tooltipster/) and it works the way i want. It made possible for me to have a tooltip with link. :))

Answer (score 0):

Try this with changes of your script!

```
array(
        'header'=>'Video Url',
        'name'  => 'video_url',
        //'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->title,$data->video_url, array("target"=>"_blank"))',
        'value' => 'CHtml::link("View Video", $data->video_url, array("target"=>"_blank"))',             
        'type'  => 'raw',
    ),
```

Perhaps you are missing `target_blank`

Comment: sorry for the late response. Thank you for your suggestion but what i really want to have is a link in the tooltip not in the value.

Comment: let me know when you found the solution =:)